# Decentralised user authentication -- possible?

Tags: authentication, language-agnostic, p2p, software-design

I'm designing a *fully distributed* P2P messaging application.

**Edit:** Not just *any* messaging application -- specifically a public forum. Messages are passed along from neighbour to neighbour, so messages may come in from a peer other than the original author. Secrecy of communication is unimportant. However, verification of the author of a message is vital.

The problem needs an introduction:

In client-server models, each client can be sure that messages' origins are what the message says they are, because there is a "middle man" authentication server that checks that the user's credentials (username, password) match an entry in an internal secret database before relaying the message to the receiving client.

The question is: **Can this be implemented in pure P2P?**

Suppose each client stores the full set of user credentials. The difference is of course that clients cannot be allowed to view them -- hence they'd be stored in encrypted format. The encrypted credentials would have to be checked for equality against another set of encrypted credentials *without ever fully decrypting either set*.

Can this be done? Is there a better way?
(Remember: 100% P2P. No servers.)

Comment: Sounds similar to what cryptocurrencies do, like bitcoin. I think blockchain is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you look into a model called [Web of trust](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_of_trust). It's used by for instance PGP to decentralize authentication.

This quote summarizes it pretty well:

> As time goes on, you will accumulate keys from other people that you may want to designate as trusted introducers. Everyone else will each choose their own trusted introducers. And everyone will gradually accumulate and distribute with their key a collection of certifying signatures from other people, with the expectation that anyone receiving it will trust at least one or two of the signatures. This will cause the emergence of a decentralized fault-tolerant web of confidence for all public keys.

Comment: @Yrlec I should have further explained what exactly I want to do. It's not a simple one-to-one messaging system, but a public forum. Everyone is to receive all messages posted by everyone. The communication does not have to be secret; only the identity of the author must be certain.

Web of Trust seems like a good start, but assuming an attacker who simply distributes fake public keys, authentication by signature becomes impossible as there's no reliable indication of which public key should be used for decoding a message.

I will clarify the question accordingly.

Comment: I think Web of trust still is one of the best decentralized solutions in your case. You could reformulate the question to: who do I trust in a network? Since you don't have a central authority which tells you who to trust you have to use some other heuristic. Web of trust essentially creates a transitive trust relation, where you trust the peers of your peers.

Comment: Another option is to try to create some form of Byzantine agreement for your authentication mechanism.

Comment: @Ylrec So is it a fact that on a P2P network where nobody trusts anybody author verification is impossible?

Comment: I don't have proof of it but intuitively I would say yes. Authentication is based on some sort of trust. What trust do you base that on if you don't trust anyone?

Comment: After research, I see the truth of what you say. I think you might find this interesting: There's apparently a more recent quorum-based model (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.15.82&rep=rep1&type=pdf) for distributed authentication. It's more resilient than a web of trust thanks to its redundancy, but more complex to implement. I think I'll go with that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a look at [PKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure). Basically, users are assigned a pair of keys, public and private. To sign a message you simply encrypt it with your private key. Anyone can decrypt it with your public key and therefore if this works it MUST have been signed by you.

There are a whole bunch of issues to understand (primarily key exchange) which is where the 'web of trust' answer above comes in...

The problem that it solves is essentially - 'How do we know that the public keys we are getting really belong to who we think they belong to?'

Comment: After some more reading, yes, that's the plan! Thanks for the comment.